# POWER QUERY: Need to change 1st number in a string depending it's value and on (2 possible) conditions from 2 other columns

Tags: powerquery

Conditional change for separate column IF the 1st digit of a string contains `"X###"`, then change to `"Y###"`

```
If DC = A and DS = 2XXX replace the 2 with a 3  
If DC = B and DS = 5XXX replace the 5 with a 6
```

Dependant Column ("DC") / Data string ("DS") / Should transform to

```
           A        2888        3888    
           B        3888        3888    
           A        8888        8888    
           B        5888        6888    
           A        2888        3888    
           B        2888        2888
```

3 conditions, 2 from another column(DC), then 1 possible replacement of the 1st digit (from DS)

I need to transform this in PowerQuery please

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar enough w/ M to know/figure out (currently) how to integrate your code into the language. If someone could kindly show me the integrated M solution most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code:

```
let
    Source = YourTable,
    types = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{"Col2", type text}),
    replace = Table.ReplaceValue(types,each Text.Start([Col2],1),
                                       each if [Col1] = "A" and Text.Start([Col2],1) = "2" then "3"
                                       else if [Col1] = "B" and Text.Start([Col2],1)="5" then "6"
                                       else Text.Start([Col2],1),Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Col2"})
in
    replace
```

Or:

```
let
Source = YourTable,
types = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{"Col2", type text}),
replace = Table.ReplaceValue(types,0,each Text.ReplaceRange([Col2], 0, 1, if [Col1] = "A" and Text.Start([Col2],1) = "2" then "3"
                                                                          else if [Col1] = "B" and Text.Start([Col2],1)="5" then "6"
                                                                          else Text.Start([Col2],1)), (a,b,c)=>c,{"Col2"})
in
    replace
```